# C# HAP "System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved " exception

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Hi I am using this code to get some data from ebay .

```
string url = textBox1.Text;
get_all_link(url);
private void get_all_link(string url)
{
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();

    try
    {
        var document = webGet.Load(url);

        MessageBox.Show(url);
        var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='ttl']/a");
        if (metaTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in metaTags)
            {
                string link = tag.Attributes["href"].Value;
                links.Add(link);
            }
        }

        var next = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='botpg-next']/a");
        if (next != null)
        {
            string link = "http://www.ebay.com" + next;
            get_all_link(link);
        }
        else return;
    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("data.txt");
        tw.WriteLine(f.ToString());
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

this is the link to be parsed : http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gruen+-sara+-quartz+-embassy+-bob+-robert+-elephants+-adidas&_sacat=0&LH_Auction=1&_dmpt=Wristwatches&_odkw=gruen+-sara+-quartz+-embassy+-bob+-robert+-elephants+-adidas&_osacat=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313 and it's writing the following exception in file

> ```
> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.ebay.comhtmlagilitypack.htmlnodecollection'
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1446
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadUrl(Uri uri, String method, WebProxy proxy, NetworkCredential creds) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1563
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url, String method) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1152
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Load(String url) in C:\Source\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1107
> at BackgroundWorker.Form1.get_all_link(String url) in C:\Documents and Settings\maruf\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BackgroundWorker\BackgroundWorker\Form1.cs:line 86
> ```

I have checked some post here . but couldn't solve this problem. How can I solve this ?? Any suggestion ?? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var next = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='botpg-next']/a");
```

Returns a `node` object and not a `string`. You need to use one of the properties of this object, likely to be somethign like `href` or `link` and use this accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding a slash between the FQDN and the path, and you are adding a `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection` to a string, which won't work.